# Why is XNA not supported in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, visual-studio-2012, monogame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)

I would like to make an game application in xna. But after purchasing vs2012 (bought it for almost 800 dollar!!) i can't use the xna game studio environment! That's crazy from MS. They are 2 products of the same company aren't? Does anybody know when vs2012 is supporting xna of monogame?

I've tried several options and search the internet already but i can't start an project in vs2012. Spend a lot of (wasted) time in it. Maybe you can help me fix this issue.

And no, i don't have vs2010 or something. It's expensive enough for me as individual. So no answers where you say; "you need to install vs2010 first..."

ridiculous from MS company. Otherwise I've to switch to an alternative. Does anyone know an alternative for developing games with xna of monogame?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @defaultlocale That contains `you still have to have VS 2010 installed`.

Comment: You mention `it's expensive enough`, but the `ridiculous MS Company` wrote the `Express` versions especially so people could get up and running for no cost at all.  This has been the case since XNA 1.

Comment: @GSerg, That's the reason why I don't put it as an answer. Still hope for better solutions

Comment: The future of XNA is in limbo right now, so you'll have to deal with the limitations that exist. One reason you need VS2010 to work with XNA 4 on Windows 8 is because VS2012 does not support the content pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the free [Visual C# 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express), and then install XNA. You won't need any features that the full (paid) Visual Studio provides.

And of course, keep an eye out for a new XNA version. I think I remember when Visual Studio 2010 came out, it took a while for the next version of XNA to come out and be compatible with 2010 - but I could be wrong.

Comment: The original XNA team moved on to other projects and some (Nick Gravelyn) quit Microsoft entirely. I wouldn't hold your breath for any new version of XNA in the near future (though I desperately hope there will be). Maybe when Xbox 720 is released? Who knows.