# vs2012 and xna4 (monogame)

Tags: c#, store, xna-4.0, monogame

I got totally sick from this "how to install xna for visual studio 2012" thing. I was searching a lot, checked out lot of tutorials, that work half as I want, and I really know that google is my friend.

I noticed that peeps use monogame nowadays, instead of xna. "SURE": so I installed monogame. Totally cool, I saw it in VS2012 too. But content...

It uses xna content as I understood, so xna developers need less time to adopt their game. Cool. Let's see tutorials... they say you should install VS2010 and then hipp-hopp back and forth to have content in your VS2012 project. Now well I do not want that.

I installed windows phone sdk 8 (or what?) so I can add xna4 content and pipeline projects in VS2012 - so... without VS2010.

Cool, but I can not make it work at all. I got content project, with a .X file in it and a .BMP so that has a texture. I added a WindowsPhoneGameLibrary too, and added content reference as well. I compile and the xnb files appear - pretty cool, I say. Then I try to link all this to the main project and nada.. it says it can not be linked (main project is monogame for windows 8 with xaml). OMG why? When I do model = content.load(etc) it can not load, since the file is not there.

So.. my simple question is: **how can I make it "just to work"? Without wizardry** or manually copying files from here to there, or without installing VS2010, and such or just without getting bald.

Comment: You realise how broad your question is right?... is your question why can i not find my content?..

Comment: I apologize. My question is in this case: how can I make it work, so I can use my content with the setup stated above? I know why I can not find the content: because I can not link the two projects. But is there a way to do it? Or do I have to compile then copy them? Or is there a way (any) to make it work as it should work: easy?

Comment: In all honesty I think you'll have more response to your question at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - I'm sorry I can't be more help right now

Comment: Is there a question somewhere there? This reads like a rant.

Comment: Yes there is: you can see it at the bottom with bold style. This is not a rant, or at least I did not meant to. I wanted to describe what I tried first, before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others, I think your question is a little ranty and I don't really understand it but I think reading these might help.

[Why is XNA not supported in vs2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707004/why-is-xna-not-supported-in-vs2012)

[How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)

In regards to your content issues:
"When I do model = content.load(etc) it can not load, since the file is not there."

Ensure all art/sound/effect assets File Properties are set properly:

- Build Action should be set to Content
- Copy To Output Directory should be Copy if newer or Copy Always

Comment: Marked your answer as answer of the question, because of wanting to be constructive and helpful. As I see there is no way to use XNA with VS2012, so I will go for Unity3D or such, what actually "just works" and this time it is a rant really LOL. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XNA with VS2012 (I do it all the time). However, if you're using MonoGame (as I understand from the post), you have to use XNA to convert your content into .xnb files and then put them into the MonoGame content folder. You can't use the Content Pipeline in MonoGame. This might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx. Even though it's Windows 8, I don't think that XNA development is different on Windows 7 and 8 (the window will just look different).

Also, if this answer helped, please mark it as the correct answer :). I'm new to the site and could use the reputation ;).

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use XNA with VS2012! Don't give up yet! :) Here's how I did it: [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)