# How to install the XNA Game Studio 4.0 in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, windows-8, xna-4.0

This question is related, but NOT a duplicate: [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)

I read the above mentioned post, and have got xna projects opening, but I now have a problem.

Some of the references to the XNA framework aren't found:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video
```

And all references to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline`

Without these, I can't compile or run any games that I've made. I can't find the dll that contains these, or where I should put them.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## UPDATE: March 3, 2014

Use the download for VS2012 and VS2013 at this link: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases. I have no idea of the legality on that project (the developers seem to have decompiled XNA), but it did help me ease the pain of needing VS2010 in order to utilize the content pipeline.

## Old Answer

See: [How to work around a possible XNA Game Studio or Windows Phone SDK install failure on Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx)

> #### How to work around this issue
>
> If you run into this issue, here are steps that you can use to work around it:
>
> - Download and install the latest version of the Games for Windows – LIVE Redistributable from http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient
> - If you are installing the Windows Phone SDK 7.1, re-run setup and choose to repair it.  This will re-run the previously failing XNA Game Studio installers and they should install correctly this time.
> - If you are install a standalone XNA Game Studio product, re-run setup and it should install correctly this time.
> - If you are planning to do Windows Phone development, you should also install the Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update after installing the Windows Phone SDK 7.1.  This update fixes an issue that prevents the emulator in the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 from working correctly on Windows 8.

> #### What to do if the workaround doesn’t help
>
> If you have tried the above steps and setup still fails, you are running into a different issue than the one described above, and you will have to look at the setup log files to determine the root cause.
>
> If you are installing the Windows Phone SDK 7.1, you can use the log collection tool to gather your setup log files. This log collection tool will create a file named %temp%\vslogs.cab.
>
> If you are installing XNA Game Studio, you can find log files at the following locations:
>
> - XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh - %temp%\XNA Game Studio 4.0 Setup\Logs
> - XNA Game Studio 4.0 - %temp%\XNA Game Studio 4.0 Setup\Logs
> - XNA Game Studio 3.1 - %temp%\XNA Game Studio 3.1 Setup\Logs
> - XNA Game Studio 3.0 - %temp%\XNA Game Studio 3.0 Setup\Logs
> - XNA Game Studio 2.0 - %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v2.0\Setup\Logs

> #### What is causing this failure behind the scenes
>
> XNA Game Studio installs a version of the Games for Windows – LIVE
>   Redistributable behind the scenes.  Some older versions of the Games
>   for Windows – LIVE Redistributable attempt to install and use a file
>   that is being installed by Windows 8, and the older versions of the
>   redistributable are not compatible with the newer version of the file
>   that is installed by Windows 8.  Newer versions of the Games for
>   Windows – LIVE Redistributable are compatible with Windows 8, and if
>   you pre-install the new redistributable before installing XNA Game
>   Studio, setup will recognize that it is already there and use the new
>   version instead of trying to install the old version.

Comment: I just found out that after restarting my PC, my game compiles. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: This Answer deserves a medal and every Thumps up!

Comment: Thank you so much! The March 3, 2014 update works well. Had a default game compiled and running in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Could you explain what is different in the new answer versus the old answer (on Aaron Stebner's blog -- which worked for me)?

Comment: @Xonatron The "updated" answer at the top links to a project which handles all of the steps for you through an installer and allows you to use newer versions of Visual Studio for the XNA content pipeline. Without it, you were required to use VS2010 for the XNA content pipeline.

Answer (score 7):

The installer for **XNA Game Studio 4.0** has some issues on **Windows 8**. The installation process fails and removes all installation files. The fact is that the main installer extracts the following installers (at c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\Setup):

- XLiveRedist.msi
- xnags_documentation.msi
- xnags_platform_tools.msi
- xnags_shared.msi
- xnags_visualstudio.msi
- xnaliveproxy.msi

The conflict is with the first one. So if you manually install all others, XNA should work fine. The problem is that after the installation failure this files are automatically deleted. My solution is to halt the installation process (using the task manager) in the moment when an error was detected, this way the installer don't have time to erase the installation files.
Once you have the files you can install it without repeating the procees.
It worked for me!!!

Comment: If you run the installer from the command line, with the /x argument, the installers are extracted manually, ie
XNAGS40_setup.exe /x

Comment: The /x option worked for me. It took a little digging around to figure what exact installers to use and the the order to install them. Take a look at the tasklist.xml that is produced by the /x and it should be fairly evident what you need to do. The XLiveRedist failed to install for me, but I was able to at least load up the projects in VS2010 on a machine that also has VS2012 & VS2013 installed.

Comment: the /x option didn't work for me, but just killing the application through the installation did work as described above.