# How can i get the 2d XNA game tutorial to run on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

I've just recently finished doing the [2D XNA game tutorial](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started) at college. Now I have to do a screencast demonstrating changes I've made to the game at home on my windows 8 system. I have Visual studio 2010 installed and XNA 4.0. I can open the game project up in Visual C# and ammend any part of the project I need to but I can not run the game.

I have tried to Install the Windows Phone Developer Tools as suggested in the XNA tutorial by when I attempt the installation it says "Windows 7 or Windows Vista is required.

Is there a work around so I can get the game to run so I can screencast it running?

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting when you attempt to run the game on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. As far as I know Microsoft dropped XNA and stopped the support for it under Windows 8 (Someone may correct me if I'm wrong). But not all hope is lost MonoGame is the open source Mono port for the XNA framework which should work under Windows 8.

This link shows how to migrate the mentioned tutorial to MonoGame and run it under Windows 8:
http://solutions.devx.com/ms/msdn/windows-client/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-3-code-migration-and-windows-8-feature-support.html

As far as I'm aware MonoGame's content pipeline doesn't work and you still need to bake the content to xnb files.

I hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is stale by now and hopefully figured it out, but in case others have similar issues, I thought I'd reply anyway.  I just ran that tutorial's game on my Windows 8 PC with no problems using Visual Studio 2010 and XNA 4 - so it works fine on Windows 8 as Microsoft still supports XNA 4 on the Windows 8 desktop (just not for Windows Store apps).  The question seems to be "how to install XNA 4 on Windows 8 and what to do about problems that might arise in attempting that?".  For that question, see the responses here: [How to install the XNA Game Studio 4.0 in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849107/how-to-install-the-xna-game-studio-4-0-in-windows-8)