# FlatRedBall XNA Game Engine

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2012

I am planning on using the FlatRedBall XNA Engine for the next game I'm planning on making, and I noticed that the .csproj files that it generated were not compatible with Visual Studios 2012. Is there any way that I can get FlatRedBall to cooperate with the new Visual Studios 2012?

Comment: Did you tried the import/convert option of visual studio 2012 ?

Answer (score 2):

The XNA 4.0 implementation of FlatRedBall will work in Visual Studio once you can get a plain XNA application working in Visual Studio 2012.  More info here:

[How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)