# install xna on visual studio 2012 on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, xna-4.0

I just installed windows 8 ultimate and visual studio 2012 ultimate on it. Later I download windows phone 8 sdk and installed for on it so that i will get xna game studio 4.0.

Now I am able to create all kind of apps except xna game for windows and xbox. That one template is missing.

I tried browsing for it and seen is couple of post that Microsoft is discontinuing with XNA? Is is true?

I want to create a touch aware windows desktop game for windows 8.

Is there any work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is XNA Game Studio has been discontinued by Microsoft or going to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 4):

First you have to install Games for Windows Marketplace Client

Download:
http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient

After completing the install of the above client software, install your XNA Studio 4 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps are touch-aware by default, and that's tangential to the use of XNA.  In fact, XNA is not an option for building Windows Store applications.

If you do have an XNA application that you want to deploy to the Windows Store, you cannot do that directly. You can, however, use the open source project [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) which implements the XNA framework API and supports deployment to Windows 8, iOS, Mac OSX, Linux, and Android.

**Update:**

If you want to continue XNA development for Windows 8 Desktop applications, that continues to be supported - take a look at [Aaron Stebner's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/09/29/10354437.aspx) for details.

Comment: can we create xna windwos game with touch support? If we have to do that we need 4.5 framework RT version and VS2012. Here I am not at all intrested in store app.

Comment: That means should developers now leave xna and start looking for other options like unity or mono game. As I read in one post that xna is discontinued by microsoft.

Comment: Xna has support for touch devices... are called windows phone... indeed the same code used for windows phone could be used to deploy to windows 8 easily.... but Microsoft has not wanted... I don't understand why...

Comment: I agree with you, but how to develop and test it? .net framework 4.5 have all touch and accelerometer stuff which working only with windows 8 RT.

Comment: sorry, I jumped to conclusion you wanted Windows Store app... see updates to my answer