# windows 8 - How to run XNA?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I have a windows 8 pc, I recently installed windows phone 7.1 sdk but it continously gave me the error that it couldn't install XNA 4.0 Refresh and MS VS 2010 Extensions for XNA. When I make a project of windows phone and run it it gives me this error:

```
Error   1   The target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryContentProjectItems" does not exist in the project. PhoneApp2
```

**Any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!**

**Thanks :)**

Comment: is any of the [guidance here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) helpful?

Comment: no, because the answer there accepted says to copy the "extension" from VS 2010 to VS 2011 and I am not able to install that "extension" that's what i mentioned in my question, @JimO'Neil

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302253/install-xna-on-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-8) & [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/09/solution-for-the-target-getcopytooutputdirectorycontentprojectitems-does-not-exist-in-the-project.html)

Comment: Those links tell me download and install XNA, which I have already done! :/ It's still not working and btw thanks for your suggesstion! :)

Comment: so to clarify - since some of the links indicate the XNA Refresh solves the problem - you get an error also installing the XNA Refresh?  If so, what's *that* error, since if that were installed (hopefully) the GetCopyToOutputDirectoryContentProjectItems would be fixed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running visual studio 2010 on Windows 8, then following the steps here should work:
http://www.demonixis.net/blog/installer-xna-4-0-sous-windows-8/

If possible you might want to uninstall what you have for xna and the windows phone sdk so far. (I'm not sure if it would work properly without doing so.)

Basically, it has three steps:

1)Go to xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient
  Start by pressing the download button on this page. I am not sure what the significance of downloading that client is, however, it did the trick when I installed it.

2)Then reinstalling xna on this page:
  microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714

3)And this last step is to download Windows SDK 7.1 here:
  microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570