# Visual Studios 2010 Windows Phone 7 to XNA 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, sdk, development-environment, xna-4.0

I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for school. I recently completed a project for the Window Phone 7 platform and am now working on an XNA3D project, however I cannot seem to change my SDK environment from WP7 to XNA.

I've opened previous projects that were started using the XNA framework, but Visual Studios opens using Windows Phone 7, not XNA. I've tried creating a new project and creating it as XNA 4.0 but when Visual Studios loads up my workspace it is still using the Windows Phone 7 header in the drop down menu at the top of the screen. The program still loads the required XNA framework, and will run my program as XNA and will not load the Windows Phone 7 Emulator, so it's not a massive in-my-face kind of problem, but it is an annoyance, and one that neither myself, nor my teacher can solve. I've played around with some of the settings and properties but nothing seems to change it. VS2010 won't even let me click the drop down arrow and select XNA, it's greyed out.

What I'm asking, is has anyone encountered this issue before, and if so, how did you resolve it? Or, do you know how I can fix this and get on with my homework?

Comment: Hi Josh, and welcome to StackOverflow. Just to let you know, we don't used signatures etc. here, so don't be offended if/when your "thanks" bit gets removed.

Comment: No worries. I just usually type a thanks by default to be polite. Thanks for the heads ups.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio identifies the project with unique projectID. And I guess this is the case for you. I highly recommended that you should update the visual studio to 2012 it is good and you can use XNA there too. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) is stackoverflow question explaining details. And it may solve your issue too.

And there is one more way, you can create new XNA project and link your all files to that project. Most of the things works there. Normally I do that while creating [Monogame] (http://monogame.net/) *A nice opensource port of XNA*.

I hope I understand your question correctly and able to answer that. Please let me know if any specific or more details required.