# XNA C# - Manually create Content folder and adding assets

Tags: c#, xna, assets

I've been trying to use **XNA** framework along with Visual Studio 2012. Since the xna framework is not yet compatible with Visual Studio *2012* I had to set it manualy.
Yet, I managed to succesfully import xna references and create default game methods allowing me to run my program.

The problem came when I tried to add *texture* to my project and load it. I manually created a "Content" folder in which I added my textures following msdn documentation at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb313966(v=xnagamestudio.30).aspx

The problem is, since it's not **XNA game project** I wont have the properties window showing my texture file as a *texture* but just as a *resource* file. 
And the following code:

```
Load<Texture2D>("GrassTexture");
```

Will systematically lead to an error **file not found**.
I've set my `ContentManger` as it follows:

```
ContentManager.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

Does anyone know how to properly set the content folder ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure just placing your file in a folder and hoping it will load will not be enough. The file has to go through the content pipeline, which is the main reason of this kind of project. Have you copied that aswell?

Comment: Load<Texture2D>("GrassTexture"); would usually work in XNA, assuming that the full line is 'Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("GrassTexture");' - Have you tried using a more complete filepath?

Comment: I don't really know how to manually add the content pipeline, I assumed it was just a folder and there was some bindings to define in csproj file. But did not find out how to.

Comment: Yes, of course, I tried a lot of absolute and/or relative paths, using extension, no extension, with everytime the same error.

Comment: Just to say, I don't think the XNA framework is ever going to be compatible with Visual Studio 2012, [I think Microsoft have killed it off](http://gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php#.URI_wKW6es6)

Comment: If you can see XNA Game Studio 4.0 in new project, then add a new project to your solution and select resource or content (something similiar to this) from XNA Game Studio 4.0. And add your content their,

Comment: I was able to get XNA working in VS 2012, Look it up, there is a question somewhere here on SO

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the option to start a new XNA Game project since it is not compatible with Visual Studio 2012 for now. I managed to get it working following the few easy steps described here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/developing-xna-apps-in-visual-studio-2012without-xna-gs/ but as for the Content management, I still don't know how to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too, but there is a opportunity to enable the xna game project for vs 12.
Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881007/1780038

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll be looking for this solution. Hope it works.