# xna on visual studio 2012 not working

Tags: visual-studio, xna

So i followed the steps in [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) and now i see the xna options but on selection i get this error "Object reference not set to instance of object"; any suggestions (I'm using vs2012 ultimate 64 on win7 64)

Comment: You shouldn't need those steps, instead try installing the v8 sdk

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this: http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/

Íf it aint working I would like to send you to the Monogame project. This is the xna library, the people from mono made it possible to port to Android, Ios, Windows 8 etc. Just use Monogame if u are having problems with installing xna on visual studios 2012. Its the perfect solution:)