# CAN XNA Works with Visual studio 2012 Express instead of 2010

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine, xna-4.0

I want to start working on game development with C#, for this I installed XNA but in requirement they said you need to have Microsoft 2010.
could it works with VS 2012

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/). I'm using it to develop XNA in Visual Studio 2012 Express and it works perfectly fine.

From their page:

> MonoGame is an Open Source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4
>   Framework. Our goal is to allow XNA developers on Xbox 360, Windows &
>   Windows Phone to port their games to the iOS, Android, Mac OS X, Linux
>   and Windows 8 Metro. Windows Phone 8, OUYA and PlayStation Mobile
>   development is currently in progress.

Answer (score 0):

according to [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6ce81c66-f87d-4a82-9ff6-e2c20070b5cc/) you can still create it, but you don't have project types in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, however it may be a little tricky and requires VS 2010 to be installed.

You should check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) here on SO about how to install it. Also [this blog post](http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/) by Ryan Lange. I had a little trouble installing it with express edition, even though the post shows how to do it. Unfortunetly I forgot what I did to make it work, so if you are using express I hope that works for you.

[MonoGame](https://monogame.codeplex.com/) is also a great alternative, however I expect you would just like to continue using XNA but with the latest IDE.