# Installing XNA Game Studio 4.0 on VS Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna, xna-4.0

I've got XNA working before on VS express before I got VS Ultimate, and followed the tutorials and got it working perfectly, but everytime I do the same tutorial with ultimate and start it up, It still says the the project is unsupported and can't seem to figure out why If someone could link me to a tutorial that works for ultimate or has a solution it would make my day. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012 - have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XNA is not compatybile with VS 2012 if you are using 2012 you may want to change to monoGame (reimplementation of XNA that works in VS 2012).

If it is VS 2010 Ultimate and you are using Windows 7 or 8 you need to install Games for Windows Client first(some liblaries are needed to install XNA corectly)

Links:

monogame: http://monogame.codeplex.com/

game for windows client: http://www.xbox.com/en-us/live/pc/downloadclient