# XNA for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xna, visual-studio-2013

Is XNA available to be used from within Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate) Preview? I have not heard, nor seen anything about XNA for VS 2013.

I have just installed VS 2013 and it's not there; I have it in VS 2012, so maybe there's a way to get it to work with 2013?

Comment: @John, are you sure that we need both the 2013 and 2013-preview tags?  I forget how it was handled for 2012.

Comment: @Charles Alot of 2013-preview questions will become irrelevant when it ships as RC due to bug-fixes etc. But there'll also be other question that are still relevant. Maybe we can merge them later on?

Comment: @Charles, bæltazor is correct. This way, issues which are fixed in the later releases can be ignored or at best unfavorited.

Comment: I have found this amazing [link](http://redwood.colorado.edu/jkb/atls-4519-s13/Docs/Building-XNA-Games-with-VS-2012-and-VS2013-Windows-for-Desktop-Express.pdf)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm running it successfully under Express 2013 Preview for Windows Desktop after following the same steps listed here for 2012: [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012).

The only difference is that the version number in the paths and manifest is now 12 instead of 11.

Comment: @bæltazor: I can't help but ask why you wouldn't consider MonoGame considering you were upset about the time you've already put into learning xna? It runs on those and more. I imagine it will continue to grow through the community as well.

Comment: Just downloaded VS 2013 after I saw this post. Anyone find a way to disable the all cap menus yet? Dosen't work the same way as VS 2012. Even more disapointed at the design of VS 2013.

Answer (score 24):

On codeplex was released new XNA Extension for Visual Studio 2013.
You can download it from: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

Comment: Wow if I would have searched for this yesterday when I first thought of it I would not have found your post. Thanks

Comment: The VS2012 method didn't work for me even when setting the version number to 12.0. This did work though.

Comment: I meant the VS2012 method didn't work for VS2013 for me. But using what you linked above **did** work!

Comment: Joe, I understand, but you reminded me, that we forgot release on the Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 5):

XNA is no longer supported. [Windows recommends MonoGame](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/XNA-and-a-Windows-8-Store-game-MonoGame). This was actually done a while ago.  And I've never seen it included. For me with 2010 Ultimate it was a separate download.

From [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/144-graphics-and-games/5404-microsoft-phases-out-xna-and-directx.html):

[According to a leaked email]

> "The XNA/DirectX expertise was created to recognize community leaders who
>   focused on XNA Game Studio and/or DirectX development. Presently the
>   XNA Game Studio is not in active development and DirectX is no longer
>   evolving as a technology. Given the status within each technology,
>   further value and engagement cannot be offered to the MVP community.
>   As a result, effective April 1, 2014 XNA/DirectX will be fully retired
>   from the MVP Award Program."

As others have commented, it may go well for you regardless of the above facts. I wouldn't count on a "Preview" version of VS to be so forgiving, but I could be completely wrong. However considering they're outright suggesting MonoGame I'd say they probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: Indeed, 2010 was the last officially supported version. There are tricks to make it work with 2012, maybe they work with 2013 as well.

Comment: Yes I've heard that. I just kept my 2010 copy installed and use that when I use XNA. It's still a good tool. I haven't bothered trying MonoGame either.

Comment: @MichaelStum tricks for 2012? Nah! It was working right after I installed it. No tricks to get it working. _Or maybe I've just forgotten._

Comment: That's the first I've heard of it going that well. I'd say it's probably possible now but I got 2012 real early and it didn't like it.

Comment: I am really pissed off right now. It took me _ages_ to figure out XNA. And just the other week something just "clicked" and I made a cool little game on my own overnight. And I have almost finished a full 2d platform game and now this? I think I just !&#% my pants.

Comment: Everytime I finally become _pretty good_ at something, it either becomes deprecated or discontinued. Sigh. Sometimes I think I should just become a bloody cleaner - but I hear they need to study for that now. Which is OK - I guess... I mean, it's not like they're going to just up and deprecate the cleaning industry... will they?

Comment: @bæltazor: Well follow the link I provided - Windows recommends... it has a link to "porting xna to monoGame. I know that in general VS C# programs compile in Mono readily. Also never tried! MonoGame is an open source implementation *of* XNA!

Comment: @C.Lang Did I read that right? Are they also discontinuing DirectX? Isn't that like, the mother of Windows Games?

Comment: [There's apparently conflicting reports on that!](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+to+discontinue+direct+x&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS468US468&oq=microsoft+to+discontinue+direct+x&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3.9200j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @C.Lang thanks :-) I am checking out the links. I'm going to give MonoGame a go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the latest download: https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases  Support for 2010, 2012, 2013

Answer (score 2):

XNA 4.0 Refresh provides support for Visual Studio 2013:
https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230

To address other comments regarding switching to MonoGame, I'll simply say that there are numerous reasons as fundamental as the inability to toggle fullscreen and change resolution during gameplay. These are open bugs since 2011. It's now 2015.

2011: http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/280127

2014: https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2495

(opened and closed several times)

Monogame is great, *but if you're only targeting Windows*, save yourself the headache and build out a game/concept/product that works on every Windows platform without work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, but I got an Installation directory that I've downloaded a time before. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C0D15621D07BDF99!2389&authkey=!AGfnvN_k5267UoM&ithint=folder%2ctxt
Download it and start the installers