# Missing Emulator List in .NET IDE

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

Any idea why my list of windows phone emulators are missing from my project? I've looked for various options in the .NET IDE and I've googled it for a while but can't find any solution to this problem.

I've got 2 other projects where this list is available but my current project doesn't list any. All I have is the Start button when I should have the following:

- Device
- Emulator WVGA 512MB
- Emulator WVGA
- Emulator WXGA
- Emulator 720P
- Etc...

Any ideas on how I can add these back to my IDE? I can still deploy to my phone via the project's properties but not very practical!

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this suggestion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048626/device-emulator-option-missing-in-xna-on-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Tried it and not working! The strangest part is that the project that was displaying the list of emulators is now messed up as well and the emulators are now missing from that one as well. I've opened a project from a third-party and that's still displaying it, whether or not I close or compile their project. It also include the new emulators I've just installed by installing SP3 emulator patch from MS. This list is also appearing in my projects but not under the start menu. They are listed in the Target Device in the properties of the project.

Comment: can you compare your project's CSPROJ file with a working one to see if there's an obvious difference?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I did and they are pretty much identical. It gets confusing once you hit difference and maybe I missed something but the very top of it is identical, bar the ProjectGuid. Totally confused. I'll make a copy of it tomorrow and remove all "files" to see what I'm left with. Maybe it will highlight some differences.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio do you use?

If you tried suggestions in [Device / Emulator option missing in XNA on Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048626/device-emulator-option-missing-in-xna-on-visual-studio-2013), try also deleting the *.SUO file of the solution.

Also, creating a new solution for windows phone (which usually displays the device list correctly) then using that *.SUO file for your current solution or simply moving all the files from the old solution to the newly created solution could work. When deleting or overwriting *.SUO files, make sure your VS is off, or the solution closed at least, otherwise it won't have any effect.

If all this fails, you might also want to try to ADD the steps from the following guide. I solved my problem by applying all the steps in this guide + steps mentioned above.

The guide: http://redwood.colorado.edu/jkb/atls-4519-s13/Docs/Building-XNA-Games-with-VS-2012-and-VS2013-Windows-for-Desktop-Express.pdf

Comment: I don't have any .SUO, and the xml section of the .csproj is identical to the one described in "Device/Emulator option missing in XNA on Visual Studio 2013". There are many other links but I'm not sure there are relevant either. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did you go through the Redwood Colorado Guide posted above?

If nothing helps, then try to create new Windows Phone Project in Visual Studio and test if the Device / Emulator options are present in the Debug / Run command. If they are, then save the project and then use both the *.SLN and *.CSPROJ files to compare them with files from the solution where these options are missing. That's how I fixed my problem. The information about the type of project and template is stored in these two files (primarily *.CSPROJ) and you need to figure which one it is.