# XNA GS installer doesn't recognize c#?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I tried installing XNA GS 4 today only to have it complain that I need to have either windows phone developer's tools, visual C++, or visual C#. I have visual C# 2013 installed already, do I have to download and install an older version of C# in order to install XNA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately XNA won't install unless you have VS 2010. Once you have it, it will actually work just fine with 2012/2013, you just need to copy the installed files over and update the .vsix manifest to allow the newer version of VS.

See [XNA for Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330810/xna-for-visual-studio-2013) or http://dementedvice.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/let-me-explain-install-xna-on-visual-studio-2013-and-2012/ for more instructions.

Comment: does M.S. not support XNA anymore or did they just not update the installer?

Comment: @ZCoder: [XNA is dead](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/185894/Its_official_XNA_is_dead.php), unfortunately.

Comment: if that case then I am left with no options. everyone has been promoting XNA like it's the only framework that works, and most tutorials depend on it. at one time I had eyed manually drawing things somehow but was strongly encouraged not to do so due to performance issues

Comment: @ZCoder, its pretty close to dead. Everything still works in normal windows, and you can hack it to work with newer versions of VS, but nothing new is being created. C++/DirectX is the way forward for "Modern" apps

Comment: @ZCoder, There are commercial frameworks like Sunburn that are also available, you may want to look into those for an XNA like coding experience.

Comment: There is also monogame which took over for XNA when XNA stopped being created.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the XNA Enabler application you will be able to install XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh into Visual Studio 2012 or 2013. 
http://what-ev.net/2014/02/19/the-xna-enabler-app-xna-in-visual-studio-2012-2013/