# There is no Video class in VS 2013? - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video, xna

I have included the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media in my project, and yet I get an error message when I try to create an object of the Video type "The type or namespace Video could not be found". I have looked in the documentation and both what I found do not help :

1. A solution states to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video, which does not exist at all for VS 2013.
2. And in the original Microsoft documentation on Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media, apparently [in here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.video.aspx), Video is indeed a class that should be existing in the library included.

What to do? I have to include a bunch of videos in my project.

Comment: Is XNA not supported anymore? (including VS 2013)?

Comment: Did you add an assembly reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`?

Comment: @GrawCube Yes I did. All references are set by default when I start the project, except this one which I cant find anywhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project .net version possibly due to a different version of the library you can not use it. Try to change .net version of your project. Or try this https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

The problem here is in the .Net Framework version, using anything but .Net Framework 4.0 does not include the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video assembly reference, simply switch from your current project version to 4.0, and the video class should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: [XNA for Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330810/xna-for-visual-studio-2013)

Also on supported Plattform it states the following:

*Xbox 360, Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP*

Are u working with >Windows 7?

Comment: I have Windows 7, Service Pack 3 installed on my computer. Sorry to disappoint.