# The debugger cannot continue running the process. Unable to start debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, xna

I used this to use my XNA game in visual studio 2012, everything worked perfectly as it looks but when I click on the debug button on the top bar, "Start Debugging" and "Start Without Debugging" are grayed out and I click on them. I can still click on the "Start" arrow, when I do I get the following error message.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What did you do to support your xna project in visual studio 2012? You need to do quite a bit of hacking to make it work. Here is a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012

Comment: yes, that is what I used, I forgot to put the link in

Comment: now if I find the executable of the project in "Projects/name/name/name/bin/x86/Debug/" it runs just fine. but If I replace bin with obj in the directory, It says "name has stopped working" and it doesn't execute. So it might be something with the obj folder

Comment: As answered by @JoachimVelzel, you need to select a project as default project http://censore.blogspot.com/2015/10/visual-studio-quirks.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

XNA Solutions come with 2 projects, the Game project and the Content project. Make sure you have the Game Project set as the "start up project". To do this right-click the game project and click "Set as start-up project", it should now work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In general, we have to set the project which is executable (web, winform, console, mobile app...) is start up project so that we can debug / run the solution

Comment: XNA projects are not like web

Comment: I mean this error can happen to any solutions which set the start up project to the project that is unable to start

Comment: OK.  Consider revising your answer to include this new information. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will find the project loading unavailable (in Solution Explorer), just need to right-click then Reload Project.

Answer (score 0):

If you run in this issue for Xbox One application (Durango) here's how I solved,

1. uninstall XDK & ADK
2. Reinstalling XDK then ADK.

Posting here so it can help someone.