# Some XNA references are missing in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna

I have carefully read [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012), and I can now create XNA projects. But, some of the references of the project are missing:

```
[ ] Microsoft.Xna.Framework
[!] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar
[ ] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
[!] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerService
[ ] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
[!] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net
[!] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage
[!] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video
[ ] Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact
```

*The projects with an exclamation mark are not found, as opposed to the others.*

What am I supposed to do in order to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. The following worked for me:

- I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010.
- I installed Visual Studio 2010.
- I installed XNA Game Studio 4.0 through [this setup](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714).
- Then I continued from step 2 of the question [How to install XNA game studio on Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) on Stackoverflow.

*Note: This solution did not involve the directories* `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft.NET` *and* `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft XNA`*.*