# Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2012 Game development

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, directx

I've read that Visual Studio 2012 can't be used with the XNA game framework so I tried to locate a version of directX which would work with visual studio 2012 on windows 7 and I can't.
It seems that directx11 is embedded in the windows sdk. I tried downloading this windows sdk but it appears that it's aimed squarely at windows 8 developers.

So, my question is this. I want to start developing some rudimentary games to help teach my some basic programming in C++ & C# but i don't want to have a copy of visual studio express installed to take advantage of XNA.

Can this be done with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7?

Comment: You can write Windows 7 (or Vista or XP) apps using the Windows 8/8.1 SDK.  What makes you think it only targets Win8 developers?

Answer (score 1):

---

`appears that it's aimed squarely at windows 8 developers`

This assumption is wrong. Windows 8 and 8.1 SDK backward compatible with older OS (both, as target OS and as development OS): [system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/bg162891.aspx#Requirements)

Also, you must have Windows 8 SDK already installed with VS2012.

---

`I've read that Visual Studio 2012 can't be used with the XNA game framework`

True. Partially. XNA is no longer *officially* supported, but:

- you can try to install XNA in VS2012 (and even VS2013) with a [bit of tweaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012) (and luck)
- you can use [MonoGame](http://monogame.net/) instead (an open source implementation of the Microsoft XNA 4.x Framework)
- you can use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) if you just need managed DirectX