# Install XNA on windows 7 which run on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, xna

Am going to do final year project of game development using xna on visual studio on windows 7, and i need help how to install xna?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012

Comment: thanks a lot, i got this